On my proof that $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$
Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a,b\neq0$. Prove $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$
so Firstly by definition
$\frac{1}{(ab)}= (ab)^{-1}$
but we know from the field axioms that this is the same as $\frac{1}{a}  \cdot \frac{1}{b}$
so this is the same as $a^{-1} \cdot b^{-1}$
Is this proof fine?

If your group is abelian, that's acceptable. Would rather avoid expressions such as $\frac{1}{x}$

This is from the first chapter of spivak, so the field is R. I don't know what a group is, sorry

Something like this: We need to show $(ab) * (a^{-1}b^{-1}) = 1$ by definition of inverse. Since you're working over the reals, you benefit from commutativity (and associativity). So:
$(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1})= (ba) * (a^{-1}b^{-1}) = baa^{-1}b^{-1} = b1b^{-1} = b*b^{-1} = 1.$
Inverses are unique, so we're done.

And by Derek's argument, this is true more generally for any nonzero $a,b$ in any field.

What you wrote works for real numbers, but you can make the proof more general by avoiding fractions and commutativity.
It's true that $x^{-1} = \frac 1x$ for any $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, but this is not definition of inverse. For $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, $x^{-1}$ is defined as real number such that $x\cdot x^{-1} = x^{-1}\cdot x = 1$. It is standard exercise to prove that if such real number exists, it is necessarily unique (and hence, notation $x^{-1}$ is justified).
Therefore, to prove that $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$ you need to prove that
$$(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab) = (ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1}) = 1$$
so $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ is an inverse and by uniqueness is the inverse of $ab$.
So, let's start
\begin{align}
(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab) &= b^{-1}(a^{-1}a)b\tag{associativity}\\
&=b^{-1}\cdot1\cdot b\tag{$a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $a$}\\
&=b^{-1}b\tag{$1$ is the multiplicative identity}\\
&= 1\tag{$b^{-1}$ is the inverse of $b$}
\end{align}
(Note that when we write $x\cdot y\cdot z$, we are also implicitly using associativity since $(x\cdot y)\cdot z = x\cdot (y\cdot z)$.)
I will leave the proof of the other equality to you.
What we wrote so far works in general, but for real numbers you can use commutativity to then conclude $b^{-1}a^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$.

I'd also like to add an intuition why the formula is $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and not $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ in general. Obviously, these are the same expressions in your case since multiplication of real numbers is commutative, but here's a real life example of the formula. Let $b$ represent putting on a sock on your foot and $a$ represent putting on a shoe on your foot. $ab$ is then composition of these two actions, first you put on your sock and then you put on your shoe. The inverse of that is obviously taking of your shoe first and only then taking off your sock, i.e. $b^{-1}a^{-1}$. In this instance, $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ would be first taking off your sock and only then taking of your shoe, which is the wrong order. Commutativity is essential for the formula you are proving to work.
(Note that I'm using convention used for function composition, $g\circ f$ means first applying function $f$ and then applying function $g$.)
